# The reference on Markov chains uncovering the power of the subject in a better way for a working macro-economist

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, markov-chains, economics, hidden-markov-models

This is by no means a research question. But asking here I hope for the most expert opinion.

A friend of mine, who is a working economist, asked me for advice about a book which uncovers wealth and mightiness of Markov chains in a possibly better way.

Since I am not an expert in the area, I have to ask the same to wider audience of experts.

Carlo Beenakker has suggested a top-notch course [Quantitative Economics with Python](https://python.quantecon.org/intro.html). This nevertheless is an introductory course.

So, reference should not necessarily be a piece of economic literature (or a resource), it may be any kind of resource uncovering wealth and mightiness of the technique. On top of that completeness combined with good positioning and presentation of material is more appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be a viable route, but if your friend is familiar with Python, a hands-on course might be an effective way to explore Markov chains. The [course](https://python.quantecon.org/intro.html) designed by Sargent and Stachurski guides you step-by-step through the basics and a variety of applications from economics. No prior knowledge is needed beyond elementary probability theory and linear algebra (plus some programming experience, but the course also includes a [module](https://quantecon.org/python-lectures/) in which the basics of Python are explained).

Comment: A first-rate and fitting answer. Thank you @Carlo

Comment: thanks; let me just one comment in connection with the updated question: while the course I linked to is introductory, there is also an [advanced module](https://python-advanced.quantecon.org)